# What is the best way to update or retrieve rows in database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I refered to Wordpress' database to create config setting for my app in Laravel. I created a `app_settings` table with `id`, `setting_name` and `setting_value` as columns to store each config name and value in rows. It works fine but the problem occurs whenever I retrieve or update data.

```
$appsetting = new AppSetting();
return $appsetting->all();
```

When I query the database it returns me a json like:

```
[
{
    "id": 37,
    "setting_name": "site_name",
    "setting_value": "Title",
    "created_at": "2015-03-09 10:40:35",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-11 03:23:48"
},
{
    "id": 38,
    "setting_name": "site_url",
    "setting_value": "http://localhost:800",
    "created_at": "2015-03-09 10:40:35",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-11 03:23:48"
},
{
    "id": 39,
    "setting_name": "site_admin",
    "setting_value": "local@host.com",
    "created_at": "2015-03-09 10:40:35",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-11 03:23:48"
}
]
```

Case 1:

Whenever I had to use a variable I had to remember the column index to get it's value. Eg. `$settings[0]['setting_value']` to retrieve `Title`and this make code pretty much static than using something like `$settings['site_name']`.

Case 2:

If I had to update multiple settings at once, I had to use multiple update commands with `where` clause.

```
$appsetting::where('setting_name', '=', 'site_name')->update(['setting_value' => $setting['title']]);

$appsetting::where('setting_name', '=', 'site_url')->update(['setting_value' => $setting['url']]);

$appsetting::where('setting_name', '=', 'site_admin')->update(['setting_value' => $setting['email']]);
```

What are the best way to update or retrieve rows in database in this case?

I want output like this while using attributes like `site_title` in rows

```
[{
    "site_title"    : "Title",
    "site_url"      : "http://localhost",
    "site_admin"    : "local@host"
}]
```

Comment: There is no way around using multiple commands to update a bunch of different records, since each update relies on unique information - the name of the setting and the value for that setting. You could create an array with the settings and values and use a foreach loop for the updates, it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @RogerHalliburton Array manipulation was something I was trying to avoid in the first place. It seems I would better stick with a table with colums than rows and probably create a column like `settings_extras` to store a json for frequently changing attributes/values.

Comment: Storing attributes/values in json has serious drawbacks if you ever want to query against that information. It also doesn't help with your array aversion, since you still have to work with an array to generate the json, and it only gets worse if you want to add more settings down the road.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($settings as $setting) {
 $output[] = array($setting['setting_name'] => $setting['setting_value']);
}
return json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered the fundamental problem with using the EAV database structure (although yours may more acurately be describes as Row Modelling) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

This type of data structure is never easy to query or update and I would recommend that you drop it and just create a config table with columns for each config var. At some point you are going to have defined all the settings that you need so you can build the table for them. If you later want to add another config setting then just add the column to the table.

That said, if you insist on using the EAV then have your code convert the results into something more usable:

```
$config = new \stdClass;
foreach($result as $row){
    $config->$row['setting_name'] = $row['setting_value'];
}

$title = $config->site_title;
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this sample will help you, but i wrote the code in Doctrine DQL:

```
    $query=$this->em->createQuery('UPDATE  Alireza\Domain\Entities\Pages_modules u
SET u.Sorder =  
     WHEN u.R THEN 'Road'
     WHEN u.M THEN 'Mountain'
     WHEN u.T THEN 'Touring'
     WHEN u.S THEN 'Other sale items'
     ELSE 'Not for sale'
WHERE  u.id IN(1,2,8,9)');
     Return $query->getResult ();
```

this type of queries do not have [n+1 problem](http://culttt.com/2013/12/30/eager-loading-laravel-4/)